# Is there a way to view the file size of an image without downloading any apps?

Tags: images, file-system

Got a new phone (Nexus S) and having some issues with picture messaging.  I want to check the size of the picture I took with the camera, but I can't seem to do this.  As I don't have a data plan yet, I can't download any apps to help me with this.  Is there a way to find the file size on the device without apps or connecting to a computer (no USB cable)

Comment: Does your Gallery app have a "Details" item in the menu when viewing a picture? On CyanogenMod I can view a picture then press `Menu->More->Details` and file size is listed there, but I don't know if it's a CM thing or a vanilla Gingerbread thing.

Comment: No file size in details unfortunately

Comment: I assume there are no free WiFi locations that you can presently connect to the Net through nearby? Perhaps like some stores / coffee shops / IT retailers etc? You can get a file manager from the market using that WiFi connection.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a file manager called "My Files"? Most Samsung phones have that by default now, although I'm unsure if Vanilla Google Android on the Nexus S will have that. Check file size through that.

Comment: No My files on Vanilla that I can see anyways

Comment: Like other Nexus phones, the Nexus S has only Google apps, with no manufacturer customizations.